# attach image from library to post with wp_insert_attachment

Tags: images

I am trying to attach some images, starting with one here for testing. It is already in the library. It seems to be trying to attach it to the post, I can see it in the media with the title of post attached but it's not actually in the post/featured image, nor is it visible when I check the post. Seems I'm almost there but missing something. Here's the code:

```
$filename = '/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/myimage.jpeg';

$post_id = 1226;

$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $post_id);

$attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id); 

  $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attach_id
  );
wp_update_post($attachment_data);
```

Comment: If the file is in the uploads folder, then it should already have an attachment post. Also when you're calling wp_update_post, what is specifying `'ID' => $attach_id` intended to DO?

Comment: It's not already attached because these images are just added to the library. The posts have no images. I intend to batch attach a bunch but was testing with one first.

Comment: I finally got it working by attaching from my desktop instead of the media library.

Comment: If they are in the media library then they are attachment posts, do you mean you copy pasted or transferred the files there rather than uploading them via the admin interface? If they show in the media library they are already attachments